# What's the use of a script that is run after login?

Tags: networking, command-line, script, terminal.app

In several different network computers (school/company/...), I noticed that a script is run in the terminal after logging in with your personal account. Why would a network administrator run a script?

Note: I am not asking about a specific case (hence I do not provide more information). It is just a question out of curiosity.

Comment: Are you referring to logon scripts or scripts that run after your desktop has loaded? There are a variety of reasons why one would use a logon script, especially on a domain like a school or company would be. I myself use multiple logon scripts even in personal environments

Comment: There's a million different reasons an administrator would run a [logon script](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770908(v=ws.11).aspx), this question is too broad to answer. A common script we run is to set up mapped drives, but again, that's one of a million

Comment: there are approximately infinite reasons. I run scripts on my linux boxes to set NumLock on, check for updates, restore security configuration, set up user environment variables, map network locations, and to make people ask questions.

Comment: This is kind of like asking what can a Swiss army knife be used for.

Comment: @BeowulfNode42  
I understand, but if you really do not know what it is, it is worth asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you login to an environment, whether it is a local computer or terminal server, a login script can be used to manage settings and access on a global scale.

For example, it is possible for a login script that runs on a rich client, to also be run when logging in to a terminal server.

To give an idea of what such script could do:

- remove all network drives
- map specific networkdrives based on membership of certain groups
- Set the default printer
- Run an installer that needs to be run on userlevel (a specific registry import script (.reg file)
- Copy files
- etc...

Yes, the list goes on with what you can do with scripts. The biggest reasons for using login are:

- You configure the script once, and any new user will quickly get the right settings.
- By using a script, settings are uniform. (everyone has the same settings)
- You can undo settings users can do to the system in order to ensure things stay the same.

A group policy could also be used in some of these cases. But a logon script existed before group policies were this advanced. And with backwards compatibility in mind, they still are being used today. And there are still things a group policy cannot do that a script can. Because vbscript can be used, you can actually display a message at login if the current time is between 23:00 and 0:00. It would even be possible to log the user out, although there are also other mechanics in place to do the same.

Answer (score 2):

> I noticed that a script is run in the terminal after logging in with your personal account. Why would a network administrator run a script?

There are plenty of reasons why any specific organization may be doing it.

In general though, it's usually implemented for setting user-level configurations that cannot be properly accessed until after the user has logged in and their profile has been loaded.